# Simplifying Update/Insert conditionals SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following stored procedure that takes a key and a timestamp and updates the timestamp using the key if the key is already present, otherwise it inserts the key along with the accompanying timestamp value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_AddUpdateTimestamp`(IN timestampKey VARCHAR(50), IN timestampValue TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
IF(timestampKey IS NOT NULL) THEN
    IF(timestampValue IS NOT NULL) THEN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM StoredTimestamps WHERE Name = timestampKey) THEN
            UPDATE StoredTimestamps SET Timestamp = timestampValue WHERE Name = timestampKey;
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO StoredTimestamps (Name, Timestamp) VALUES (timestampKey, timestampValue);
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM StoredTimestamps WHERE Name = timestampKey) THEN
            UPDATE StoredTimestamps SET Timestamp = NOW() WHERE Name = timestampKey;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO StoredTimestamps (Name, Timestamp) VALUES (timestampKey, NOW());
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;
END
```

To me, this is a lot of conditional logic and makes this procedure very verbose. Does anyone know a way this logic can be simplified?

Comment: Use MERGE command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO StoredTimestamps (Name, Timestamp)
    VALUES (timestampKey, COALESCE(timestampValue, NOW()) )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Timestamp = VALUES(timestampValue);
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` sets the `Timestamp` to the value being inserted, when the `Name` already exists.

For this to work, you need a unique index/constraint on `Name`:

```
ALTER TABLE StoredTimestamps ADD CONSTRAINT unq_StoredTimestamps_Name UNIQUE (Name);
```

In a stored procedure, I would be careful about naming conventions as well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_AddUpdateTimestamp (
    IN in_timestampKey VARCHAR(50),
    IN in_timestampValue TIMESTAMP)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO StoredTimestamps (Name, Timestamp)
        VALUES (in_timestampKey, COALESCE(in_timestampValue, NOW()))
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Timestamp = VALUES(timestampValue)
END;
```

I prefer `usp_` rather than `sp_` due to my history of using SQL Server, where `sp_` is discouraged because it is used for system stored procedures.  That is simply a habit and not really relevant to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the line ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Timestamp = VALUES(Timestamp)